# Mutidimensional arrays in c won't accept my inputs

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

/*  In the program below, i want to accept marks of any number of students in 5 subjects, store them in an array called "marks", and then calculate the average marks f each student over all 5 subjects.
    however it only seems to accept the marks of the last student you enter.

I want to know the bug in the program ?

---

```
   {
    char subject[5][10]=
    {
        "Maths",   
        "Physics",
        "English",
        "Chemistry",
        "Biology",
    };


    char student[30][20],ans;
    int marks [30][5],i,j,nos, total;
    float studavg[30], subavg[5];
    main()
    {
        for (ans='y',i=0;i<30 && ans=='y';i++)
        {
            printf("\nEnter student number: %d",i+1);
            gets(student[i]);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("more? (y/n)");
            ans=getchar();
            fflush(stdin);    
        }
        nos=i;
/*that part initializes my student array and saves the no of students*/

        for (i=0;i<nos;i++)
        {
             for (j=0;j<5;j++)
             {
                 marks[i][j]=0;
                 printf("Enter the marks for %s in %s",student[i],subject[j]);
                 scanf("%d",&marks[i][j]);
                 fflush(stdin);    
             }                  
         }      
    /*this part is supposed to create an array of student marks*/


        for (i=0;i<nos;i++)
        {
            for (j=0;j<5;j++)
            {
               total+=marks[i][j];           
            }
            studavg[i]=total/5;
         }
     }

/*the last part was to find the student average*/}
```

Comment: Never use `gets`; it is inherently unsafe and has been removed from the language. Use `fgets` instead; it's a bit more complicated to use, but you can limit the size of the input it accepts. Don't use `fflush(stdin)`; it has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must clear `total` for each new student:

```
for (i = 0; i < nos; i++)
{
    for (j = total = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
       total += marks[i][j];
    }
    studavg[i] = total / 5;
}
```

Comment: Moreover total is not initialized

Comment: @zoska True, but that's taken care of by my fix, too. :)